# Is closed set regular-closed in some topological spaces?

Tags: general-topology

The definition of  regular closed sets  is:

> Let $X$ be a topological space and $A\subseteq X$. We say that $A$ is a regular closed if $A=\text{cl}(\text{int}(A))$

We know that the regular closed sets  is closed.

> Is there a topological space  so that the  closed sets  is regular-closed ?for example  in Hausdorff or regular space or ..........  .

Comment: A discrete topological space is an example.

Comment: A trivial class of such spaces are the discrete spaces, where every subset of the space is both open and closed.

Comment: Except for discrete space, Is there another example?

Comment: You'd need to consider non-$T_1$ spaces to find other examples.  For instance any indiscrete space.

Comment: Prove that the closure of all singletons $\{x\}$, for $x\in X$ are clopens that partition $X$. Then, the topology is given by arbitrary unions of those sets. So, topological spaces in which all closed sets are regular closed are those in which the topology consists of arbitrary unions of elements of a partition of $X$.

Comment: Also see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3169975/4280)

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is $T_1$, the set $\{x\}$ is closed but regular closed iff $x$ is an isolated point.

So the only $T_1$ examples are discrete. The indiscrete/trivial topology is an example that is not $T_1$. In fact Eric Wofsey shows in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3170002/4280) that the only examples are the ones where the topology is generated by a partition. (All singletons for the discrete case, a single $\{X\}$ in the indiscrete case).

As a side note, there is a nice (but weird) class of spaces called [extremally disconnected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremally_disconnected_space) where the closure of an open set is again open, so regular closed sets are clopen.

If a space $X$ is regular then the regular open sets form a base for its topology, and so by duality the regular closed sets form a "closed base" (every closed set is an intersection of regular closed sets).